# Forms Authentication Error CD cluster - The current user cannot be resolved from the authentication cookie. The cookie will be removed

Tags: login, scaling

We are using `Forms based authentication` in our `Sitecore 10` solution. We have configured ``Redis as our Private and Shared `Session` Store. The `authentication` and user login works fine in a single CD server environment. However, when we are using multiple CD servers and doing `load balancing`, we get a message in log file saying,

> "The current user cannot be resolved from the authentication cookie.
> The cookie will be removed."

and the user is not able to login. Tried changing to SQL Server session store and still got same error. Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Found that had to set the decryption and encryption key to same values in both the CD servers. It was my bad I missed it. Found the info from the documentation link, https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/configure-multiple-content-delivery-instances.html . Thank you all.